# Windows 10 taskbar text for Python matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm learning Python and I do a lot of plotting using matplotlib. My main language, currently, is Matlab and I do a lot of plotting in it too. If I have a lot of plots at the same time I find it very useful to change the default text for that plot on the **Windows Taskbar** from the default "Figure 10" to something that tells me what the plot is about. In Matlab I use:

```
set(gcf,'NumberTitle','off');
set(gcf,'Name',string);
```

And the chosen string appears on the Window Taskbar icon for that figure. Matplotlib also, by default, just says "Figure 10" (or whatever the figure number is). Is there an equivalent in matplot lib or in Python?

Comment: please format your code

Comment: this has nothing to do with the taskbar as you are giving a name to a window (BTW, you can do this right away when opening a figure in MATLAB `figure('Name','This is my window'). I know that you can do this with *opencv* but with matplotlib I usually simply plot into the commandline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a window title to `plt.figure('My title')` when you create the [figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html). The actual parameter name confusingly is called `num`, which is related to the default names being 'Figure 1', 'Figure 2' etc..  When `num` is a string, it will replace that default title.

To create the figure with `plt.subplots`, `num` can be given explicitly: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(..., num='My title')`.

If the figure is already created earlier, change its window title with
`fig.canvas.set_window_title('My new title')`. To get handle to the current figure: `fig = plt.gcf()`.

It's this window title that will be displayed in the taskbar.

Here is an example involving a seaborn joint plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.gamma(2, size=1000)
y = -.5 * x + np.random.normal(size=1000)

sns.jointplot(x, y, kind="hex", color="purple")
plt.gcf().canvas.set_window_title('Seaborn joint plot')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: I did upvote, but I didn't have enough reputation votes for it to register. I do now. I have also accepted the answer. I spent hours googling without finding the solution, so thanks again.